# How damaging would a dragon with an aqua regia breath weapon be?

Tags: science-based, dragons, natural-weapons

Assume a dragon, roughly the size of a shire horse. This dragon has a unique breath weapon, that *technically* "burns" (oxidizes) the target.

Still, I have a hard time imagining how dangerous and damaging would that weapon be against knights (in plate armor) and mundane structures.

A dragon can expel a maximum of 3 liters of aqua regia, after that, they need some time to refill the storage organs. The nitric and hydrochloric acids are kept separate, and only combine  shortly before exiting the dragon, and don't even properly combine when the dragon uses their *spray* mode. Proper aqua regia is only created when the dragon uses the *spit* or *drool* modes. Dragons prefer to use their spray mode for combat.

There are two main points to the knight:

1. **How fast will they die from a direct and a grazing hit?**
2. **Before that, how fast will they be incapacitated from a direct and a grazing hit?**

Comment: What's that about Elon Musk's junk??

Comment: @ArkensteinXII That joke of a flamethrower?

Comment: I feel like oblique references in a question don't lead to clear answers.

Comment: In addition, I would say this question has insufficient detail.  How far can the dragon spray their acid?  What volume of acid?  What concentration?  How many mols/unit volume at various points?  There's a big difference if a "direct hit" delivers one litre of aqua regia, or a hundred.

Comment: *Still, I have a hard time imagining how dangerous and damaging would that weapon be against knights (in plate armor) and mundane structures* Compared with WHAT? since there are no actual dragons, you should explain what a "normal" dragon can do so we can answer. Compared against a dragon that splits sulphuric acid it would not make much of a diference, unless the knights armour is made of gold.

Comment: Another critical factor is the temperature. Very roughly the speed of chemical reactionss doubles for every 10 degree rise in temperature. So an aqua regia at 0 degrees C is one thing and aqua regia at 100 degrees C is quite another.

Comment: @Slarty Pressure is important too.  A pressure washer spraying acid will do more damage than a squirt gun spraying acid.

Answer (score 9):

Weaponised acid is a thing in the natural world ([termites vs ants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmrEShkiK5Y)).

As far as your acid spitting dragon, goes, here's what happens when [Chlorosulfonax the Acrid faces off against the Immobile Chicken of Endor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XEdBLlvYrE). A normal, mobile animal will instantly turn and seek to flee the vapours.

This weapon will be of great effect against anything that breathes. The knights, their horses and their horses' footmen will all suffer greatly upon [inhaling the dragon's breath](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1353113106001957). Even though the acid won't dissolve the knights right away, they will suffer terribly: their skin will be burnt; their mucous membranes -- nasal, oral, throat, lungs -- will be burnt, swell up and maybe cause death; they're probably be blinded. If they survive, they will be disfigured & disabled.

Little difference between this and the chemical attacks used in WWI, and that's the avenue of research you'll probably want to go down next.

Comment: This would be the effect on unprepared knights. The knights preparing to fight the "acid dragon" would cover themselves in wet fabric, greatly reducing the effect of the attack.

Comment: @Alexander They still breathe, and inhaling nitric acid is lethal. Aside from the damage, it triggers convulsive closure of the airways at concentrations as low as 200ppm (0.4 grams per cubic meter). The resultant dyspnea is 100% disabling, and without treatment death follows within minutes. WITH treatment, death follows 90% within 2 days.

Comment: @PcMan The knights would be using face masks, of course.

Comment: @Alexander Knights have access to masks that filter gaseous and sub-micron acidic particulates? WOW. **we** did not have that until late in WW1. I never knew plate armor for knights came equipped with 19th-century chemical protection.

Comment: @PcMan first, don't underestimate the effect of multilayer wet cloth. Second, why are we going to have "sub-micron acidic particulates"? This mist, even if dragon is able to produce it, won't travel well in the air.

Comment: @Alexander you... have never worked with fuming nitric acid, have you? You show utter ignorance, indeed suicidal ignorance, of the nature of the chemical. Please absent yourself from this discussion, you are embarrassing yourself and detracting from the experience of people that actually might be interested in the discussion.

Comment: @PcMan Oh, come on please. FYI, I have a M.S. in organic chemistry. While concentrated nitric acid is indeed a nasty thing, once diluted it's becoming a lot less dangerous. We need a lot and lot of acid to spoil the air (unless it the acid reacts with something on the ground). Another particular danger that you mentioned is aerosols - but they won't form easily, and as I said, aerosols won't travel in the air nearly as good as a jet of liquid. Dragon can hit someone with a spray only at point blank range.

Comment: @Alexander You claim to have an MS in chemistry, yet you believe wet cloth will stop acid gas? That is simply not true. Yes it will help a bit (a lot actually) but not sufficiently to protect the wearer from lung damage. Please pay attention to the OP's post. The dragon spits "Aqua Regia", which requires highly concentrated nitric acid, not the dilute stuff.

Comment: @Alexander  Also pay attention to the phrase "Dragons prefer to use their spray mode for combat.".. You contesting that the spray does not work is calling the OP a liar. If you wish to contest the OP's facts, do so in a frame challenge answer. But do NOT do so by injecting snide untruths into comments.

Comment: @PcMan and Alexander --- can you guys tone it down? And take it to chat!